# Why are includes not compatible with RTCZero library?

Tags: c++, c, struct, compiler-errors, arduino

Long story short, I am using RTCZero library to create an alarm to wake up my arduino, after some time, but I have ascertained, that when I add more sensors, with more libraries, RTC library is not compatible with them. I thought that it is caused my including , but problem still persists. Any solution?

!!!EDIT!!!

More precisely, I found, that problematic libraries are only these: Here you can download whole library (includes in this script are in). https://github.com/charles-the-forth/openCanSat-library

```
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h> 
#include <Adafruit_INA219.h>
#include "Open_Cansat_GPS.h"
#include "RFM69.h"
```

Here are includes

```
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>  // include Adafruit BME280 library
#include <Adafruit_INA219.h>  // include INA219
#include <SD.h>          // include Arduino SD library
#include "Open_Cansat_GPS.h"

//include our new sensors
#include <MICS6814.h>
#include <MICS-VZ-89TE.h>
#include "MQ131.h"
#include <Wire.h>

#include "RFM69.h"       // include RFM69 library
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RTCZero.h>
```

Here are the errors

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Vývojová deska: "Arduino M0"

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp: In member function 'uint32_t RTCZero::getEpoch()':

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:379:13: error: aggregate 'RTCZero::getEpoch()::tm tm' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

   struct tm tm;

             ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:391:10: error: 'mktime' was not declared in this scope

   return mktime(&tm);

          ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:391:10: note: suggested alternative: 'mktemp'

   return mktime(&tm);

          ^~~~~~

          mktemp

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp: In member function 'void RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)':

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:22: error: 'gmtime' was not declared in this scope

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

                      ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:22: note: suggested alternative: 'setTime'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

                      ^~~~~~

                      setTime

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:409:21: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmDate(tmp->tm_mday, tmp->tm_mon + 1, tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF);

                     ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:409:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmDate(tmp->tm_mday, tmp->tm_mon + 1, tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF);

                       ^~~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:409:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmDate(tmp->tm_mday, tmp->tm_mon + 1, tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF);

                                   ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:409:37: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmDate(tmp->tm_mday, tmp->tm_mon + 1, tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF);

                                     ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:409:52: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmDate(tmp->tm_mday, tmp->tm_mon + 1, tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF);

                                                    ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:409:54: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmDate(tmp->tm_mday, tmp->tm_mon + 1, tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF);

                                                      ^~~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:410:21: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmTime(tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);

                     ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:410:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmTime(tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);

                       ^~~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:410:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmTime(tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);

                                   ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:410:37: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmTime(tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);

                                     ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:410:48: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmTime(tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);

                                                ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:410:50: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     setAlarmTime(tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);

                                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:407:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setAlarmEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp: In member function 'void RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)':

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:22: error: 'gmtime' was not declared in this scope

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

                      ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:22: note: suggested alternative: 'setTime'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

                      ^~~~~~

                      setTime

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:426:29: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.YEAR = tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF;

                             ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:426:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.YEAR = tmp->tm_year - EPOCH_TIME_YEAR_OFF;

                               ^~~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:427:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.MONTH = tmp->tm_mon + 1;

                              ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:427:32: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.MONTH = tmp->tm_mon + 1;

                                ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:428:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.DAY = tmp->tm_mday;

                            ^~

Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "Wire.h"
 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.8.4\libraries\Wire
Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "SD.h"
 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SD
 Nepoužitý: C:\Program
C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "MICS6814.h"
     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino-mics-6814-master
            ^~

Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "MICS-VZ-89TE.h"
C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:428:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MICS-VZ-89TE-master
Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "MQ131.h"
     clockTime.bit.DAY = tmp->tm_mday;

 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\mq131
                              ^~~~~~~

 Nepoužitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ozone
 Nepoužitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\hjj
Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "SPI.h"
 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.8.4\libraries\SPI
C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "RTCZero.h"
C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:429:29: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master
     clockTime.bit.HOUR = tmp->tm_hour;

                             ^~

Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "Adafruit_BME280.h"
 Použitý: C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\openCanSat-2.0-library-master
C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:429:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.HOUR = tmp->tm_hour;

                               ^~~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:430:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.MINUTE = tmp->tm_min;

                               ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:430:33: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.MINUTE = tmp->tm_min;

                                 ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:431:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.SECOND = tmp->tm_sec;

                               ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:431:33: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     clockTime.bit.SECOND = tmp->tm_sec;

                                 ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Marty\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RTCZero-master\src\RTCZero.cpp:422:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct RTCZero::setEpoch(uint32_t)::tm'

     struct tm* tmp = gmtime(&t);

            ^~

exit status 1
Nastala chyba při kompilaci u desky Arduino M0.

Táto zpráva by měla mít víc informacií v
"Zobrazení podrobného výstupu při kompilaci"
podle zapnuté volby v Soubor -> Nastavení.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `RTCZero.cpp` you can see `#include <time.h>` which is standard header and library rely on it.

In linked library (openCanSat) you can see Time.h and Time.cpp which is some custom implementation of time functions and it's completely incompatible with standard time.h. However, because Arduino IDE is such a dummy IDE, the `Time.h` took precedence before `time.h` (this won't happen on OS with case sensitive filesystems - like linux, osx, ...). So you can either rename Time.h in the library, or you can try changing `#include <time.h>` to `#include <ctime>`, but it's probably including time.h too, so...